# How to use assemblies in a VS solution under source control and keep assemblies updated?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies

(I no longer want an answer. OML, my English has surely improved...)

How to use assemblies in a VS solution under source control and keep assemblies updated?
(Source control is provided by the codeplex and VS default options for it.)
I mean,I have a project named HyperAero.
I have another project named TestAnimation.
TestAnimation is under source control and needs hyperaero.
When I check in,HyperAero.DLL will not be saved in server.Of course,I can add hyperaero.dll to my solution as a file but I want it to stay updated with my changes in HyperAero project automatically.
What should i do?
Answer (Got it myself):
command:
robocopy "E:\Documents\My VS\Fix soft HyperAero Form\Fix soft HyperAero\bin\Release" "E:\Documents\My VS\Fix soft Animation Maker\Test of Animation Maker\DLLs" "*.DLL"
set rce=%errorlevel%
if not %rce%==1 exit %rce% else exit 0

Similar Question (Remember that i want my assemblies to stay updated):
When using custom assemblies in a visual studio project. How does one check in those assemblies in source control with the project so that anyone can download the project and build right away.

Comment: This largely depend on the kind of source control system you are using. And you have not specified which is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put both projects in the same solution and add a project reference.
2. Use your source control's UI / command-line to add the DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to approach this:

1/ Don't put the assembly dependencies in source control and always include in your solution their Visual Studio project instead. In your case you'd have a solution with the Hyperaero project and TestAnimation project with a **project dependency** to the Hyperaero project.

This way you don't have to put the generated DLL in source control and keep it updated each time you change something in the code.

2/ If you really want to dissociate both projects, then I'll recommend you to use Nuget and build a Nuget package for the Hyperaero project and then reference the Nuget Package in you TestAnimation project. This approach is the cleanest one, but it may be overkill and at last it's not something you'll setup quickly (compared to 1/).

Answer (score 0):

What source control software do you use?

If you are using `subversion`:

- ankhsvn (Visual Studio plugin) can handle multipe repositories in one solution.

I have the following structure.

```
- App1\
  App1.sln
  App1Forms\
    App1Forms.csprj
- App2\
  App2Dll\
    App2Dll.csprj
```

Now If I open App1.sln and add App2Dll, which is outside the folder structure, as a project, the project gets linked as a relative path. I am fine, if I check out both sources to the same parent directory.

Ankh is aware of that and If I hit `update` both projects gets updated.
If I want to commit changes I am only allowed to commit to one repository at a time, but again, ankh informs me about that.

Another way is to use svn-externals http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html
which will transparently include one repository inside another.